# Problem with two scripts interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, slider

I'm trying to bring some images from a Tumblr account and to show them using a slider. To bring the images I modified and used a script called tubmlrBadge (http://robertnyman.com/2008/09/19/tumblrbadge-a-tumblr-badge-script/), and to show the images I am using this slider > http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx 
If I check using Firebug I can see that the photos are shown okay, but I can't see them in with the slider. I can't figure out what's the problem, I suppose that a problem appears because the slider script must work with content generated by the tubmlr script. I tried placing the slider script after the tumblr one the slider still doesn't works.
You can see a demo of the this at http://www.mctest2.com.ar. If anyone has an idea please help me I tried everything!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script you use to fetch the images was the image-fetcher itself (not a script that calls another script to get a JSON with the image data) you would have used [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) with a callback method.

However, [your script](http://www.mctest2.com.ar/scripts/tumblrBadge-1.1ext.js) can't use it, because no matter if the script file is loaded, it will also call another one, that might take longer to be loaded.

I think the only possibility you have is to set an "timer" in your page and wait until the gallery is loaded:

```
function setSlider() {
    var jqelement = $('.gallery img');
    if(jqelement.length>0) {
        jqelement.slidingGallery();
    } else {
        setTimeout(setSlider, 200);
    }  
}

setSlider();
```

### Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/5dSgd/